# How can I make codepipeline run even there is failed action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have deployed a codepipeline with a few stages and each stage includes a few actions.
The pipeline will stop if one of the stage fail to run.

Is there a way to configure codepipeline to run all stages even there are failed ones?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to enable  **continue on error** kind of feature in **AWS CodePipeline**.

But, you can do that in **AWS CodeBuild**. You have this `on-failure` field to define whether you want to *CONTINUE* or *ABORT* the phase in case of failure.

```yaml
phases:
  install:
    run-as: Linux-user-name
    on-failure: ABORT | CONTINUE  <---- This option
    runtime-versions:
      runtime: version
    commands:
      - command
      - command
```

Read more at [build-spec.phases.on-failure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases.on-failure).

Comment: Oh, does it show the failed build as failed or success?

Comment: That I have not tried, but you can :)

Comment: it turns out that the on-failure only control the flow inside codebuild not codepipeline